# Pass argument in to bash script(curl)

Tags: bash, curl

have script in gitlab,the task is simple, run the script by passing 2 arguments

i use command :

```
bash <(curl -Ls "https://gitlab.com/sdf/sdf/-/raw/sdf-main-patch-23022/script.sh?inline=false") domain.xyz 8000
```

in the script, a simple code:

```
let a=$1
let b=$2
```

my command work but get error: `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".xyz")`

I understand that this is how it is written that arithmetic is being performed .. but you see what I want to do?

Here it is clearly that I am doing something wrong, I do not understand well. in the bash, can someone tell me what is wrong here?

but for example, if you do this, everything works without errors ..

```
bash <(echo 'echo args: "$1$2"') domain.xyz 8000
```

help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let command used to evaluate arithmetic expression, so its not able to recognise a dot(.) character as a valid input because dot(.) is not a valid arithmetic operator.

so, if you want to take arguments in a variable, define then without let keyword like given code.

```
a=$1
b=$2

echo $a
echo $b
```